# Writing AWS Lambda function for PUT in Firehose

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I'm new to Lambda and am trying to emulate a simple function to do a PUT into Kinesis Fireshose.

I have tried looking thru AWS docs, but am unable to find any exact references to write a simple python script to do a GET from an API and send JSON to S3 via Firehose. Below is the code I'm trying to post to Lambda, but instead of filesystem, I wanted to send this to Firehose on a scheduled basis.

```
# Get weather from OWM and use args for correct type.
def get_weather(gtype, lat, lon, key):
    if gtype == 'current':
        apitype = "weather?"
    elif gtype == 'forecast':
        apitype = "forecast?"
    else:
        print("Undefined GET type: use 'current' or 'forecast'.")
    try:
        api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/" + apitype
        PARAMS = {'lat': lat, 'lon': lon, 'appid': key}
    except:
        return 'Invalid GET request'
    with requests.session() as s:
        rc = s.get(url=api, params=PARAMS)
    data = rc.json()
    return data

# Write data to json files.
def write_to_current(location, gtype, lat, lon, key):
    with open(location + '/current.json', 'w') as outfile:  
        json.dump(get_weather(gtype, lat, lon, key), outfile)
    return 'Current write complete.'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a sample [code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-kinesis-firehose_to_s3.py.html) from AWS to write to S3 and
the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/firehose.html) for Amazon Web Services (AWS) SDK for Python.

Also, you can checkout the [Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose api reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) documentation